# how to draw text to byte array using winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to draw text to byte array, to convert it later to DirectX11 texture.
I was trying many thinks, for example like this:

```
HDC hdc= GetDC( g_hWnd );
int w= 600;
int h= 450;
    unsigned* buf= new unsigned [w*h];
for( int a=0;a<w*h;a++)buf[a]= 0x0;
HBITMAP hbmp= CreateBitmap( w, h, 1, 4*8, buf );    
if(!hbmp)throw "error bmp";
HDC vhdc= CreateCompatibleDC( hdc );
if(!vhdc)throw "error vhdc";
SelectObject( vhdc, hbmp );
TextOut( vhdc, 0, 0, L"TEST", 4 );
```

But after that buf is still empty.
I need it for intro 64KB, so I can not use big libraries.

Here is another not working code that I tried:

```
unsigned* buf= new unsigned [w*h];
for( int a=0;a<w*h;a++)buf[a]= 0x0;
HDC vhdc= CreateCompatibleDC( hdc );    if(!vhdc)throw "vhdc is hard";
HBITMAP hbmp= CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, w, h );
BITMAPINFO bmi = {{sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),w,-h,1,32,BI_RGB,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}};
SelectObject( vhdc, hbmp );
TextOut( vhdc, 0, 0, L"TEST", 4 );

BITMAPINFO bmpi;
ZeroMemory( &bmpi, sizeof(bmpi) );
//GetDIBits(vhdc, hbmp, 0, h, buf, &bmpi, NULL);
GetDIBits(vhdc, hbmp, 0, h, buf, &bmpi, BI_RGB);
```

I was using vhdc and hdc as GetDIBits argument, non of it work.

Comment: when you use bitmap with SelectObject, then this bitmap must be a compatible bitmap. Use CreateCompatibleBitmap instead of CreateBitmap. After text drawing you can get raw bytes from your bitmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateBitmap` only uses the given data as input. The buffer is not updated when you draw on it. You should use `CreateDIBSection` instead.

Comment: OK. It was my mistake when I was testing your answer. It work.

Answer (score 2):

jlahd already have answered the question.
But I will post working code in case anybody need it.

```
HDC hdc= GetDC( g_hWnd );  /// g_hWnd is my windows handle type HWND
int w= 1024;
int h= 768;

unsigned* buf= new unsigned [w*h];

HDC vhdc= CreateCompatibleDC( hdc );    if(!vhdc)throw "error with vhdc";
HBITMAP hbmp= CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, w, h );
BITMAPINFO bmpi = {{sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),w,-h,1,32,BI_RGB,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0}};
SelectObject( vhdc, hbmp );
TextOut( vhdc, 10, 10, L"HELLO WORLD", 11 );
GetDIBits(vhdc, hbmp, 0, h, buf, &bmpi, BI_RGB);
```

After that code buf store data with image with "HELLO WORLD" drawed on it.